# Como buscar datos en un ArrayList de otro ArrayList

Tags: java, array, poo, herencia, constructor

Estoy haciendo un programa en Java tengo dos clases en las que estoy haciendo el ArrayList una llamada Materia y otro ArrayList en una llamada Estudiante cabe recalcar que de la clase Estudiante cree un constructor sobrecargado dado que solo me interesan dos datos que son nombre y apellido , mi duda que por ejemplo si quiero implementar la opcion buscar un datos en un arraylist como podria hacer que esa busqueda me permite buscar el dato del otro ArrayList tambien .

CLASE ESTUDIANTE

```
public class Estudiante extends Persona {
    private String carrera;
    private String semestre;
    private String fechaingreso;
    private String fechafinalizacion;
    private int materiasXsemestre;

    public Estudiante(String carrera, String semestre, String fechaingreso, String fechafinalizacion, int materiasXsemestre, String nombre, String apellido, int cedula, String fechadenacimiento, int telefono, String direccion) {
        super(nombre, apellido, cedula, fechadenacimiento, telefono, direccion);
        this.carrera = carrera;
        this.semestre = semestre;
        this.fechaingreso = fechaingreso;
        this.fechafinalizacion = fechafinalizacion;
        this.materiasXsemestre = materiasXsemestre;
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.apellido=apellido;
    }
    public Estudiante(String nombre,String apellido){
        super(nombre,apellido);
    this.nombre=nombre;
    this.apellido=apellido;
    }
         
    public String getCarrera() {
        return carrera;
    }

    public void setCarrera(String carrera) {
        this.carrera = carrera;
    }

    public String getSemestre() {
        return semestre;
    }

    public void setSemestre(String semestre) {
        this.semestre = semestre;
    }

    public String getFechaingreso() {
        return fechaingreso;
    }

    public void setFechaingreso(String fechaingreso) {
        this.fechaingreso = fechaingreso;
    }

    public String getFechafinalizacion() {
        return fechafinalizacion;
    }

    public void setFechafinalizacion(String fechafinalizacion) {
        this.fechafinalizacion = fechafinalizacion;
    }

    public int getMateriasXsemestre() {
        return materiasXsemestre;
    }

    public void setMateriasXsemestre(int materiasXsemestre) {
        this.materiasXsemestre = materiasXsemestre;
    }
    
    
}
```

Ahora les voy a adjuntar la clase Materia solo el constructor que use

```java
public class Materia {
    protected String nombremateria;
    private String codigomateria;
    private String semestre;
    private String idmateria;
    protected double calificacionp1;
    protected double calificacionp2;
    protected double calificacionp3;
    protected double notafinal;

    public Materia(String nombremateria, String codigomateria, String semestre, String idmateria, double calificacionp1, double califacacionp2, double califacacionp3, double notafinal) {
        this.nombremateria = nombremateria;
        this.codigomateria = codigomateria;
        this.semestre = semestre;
        this.idmateria = idmateria;
        this.calificacionp1 = calificacionp1;
        this.calificacionp2 = califacacionp2;
        this.calificacionp3 = califacacionp3;
        this.notafinal = notafinal;
    }
    public Materia(String nombremateria,double calificacionp1, double califacacionp2, double califacacionp3){
             this.nombremateria = nombremateria;
             this.calificacionp1 = calificacionp1;
             this.calificacionp2 = califacacionp2;
             this.calificacionp3 = califacacionp3;
            
    }
```

Ahora les envio la clase profesor en esta clase tengo los arraylist ahi me gustaria hacer la busqueda en el metodo buscar osea por ejemplo pongo el nombre y me deberian salir los datos de arraylist Estudiante solo nombre , apellido y el del otro arraylist de la clase materia

```java
public class Profesor extends Persona {
     ArrayList<Estudiante> Estudiantes =new ArrayList<Estudiante>();
    ArrayList<Materia> Materias =new ArrayList<Materia>();
   
    private int carreras;
    private int materiasdadas;

    public Profesor(int carreras, int materiasdadas, String nombre, String apellido, int cedula, String fechadenacimiento, int telefono, String direccion) {
        super(nombre, apellido, cedula, fechadenacimiento, telefono, direccion);
        this.carreras = carreras;
        this.materiasdadas = materiasdadas;
    }   

    public int getCarreras() {
        return carreras;
    }

    public void setCarreras(int carreras) {
        this.carreras = carreras;
    }

    public int getMateriasdadas() {
        return materiasdadas;
    }

    public void setMateriasdadas(int materiasdadas) {
        this.materiasdadas = materiasdadas;
    }
 

    
    public void ingresoCalificaciones(){
      Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
      try{
      Materia m = new Materia("Calculo Integral","034f","II","1",10.4,8.6,9.3,8.2);
      System.out.println("INGRESE EL NOMBRE DEL ESTUDIANTE");
      nombre=sc.nextLine();
      System.out.println("INGRESE EL APELLIDO DEL ESTUDIANTE");
      apellido=sc.nextLine();
      System.out.println("INGRESE EL NOMBRE DE LA MATERIA");
      m.nombremateria=sc.nextLine();
      System.out.println("INGRESE LA CALIFICACION DEL PRIMER PARCIAL");
      m.calificacionp1=sc.nextDouble();
     System.out.println("INGRESE LA CALIFICACION DEL SEGUNDO PARCIAL");
      m.calificacionp2=sc.nextDouble();
      System.out.println("INGRESE LA CALIFICACION DE RECUPERACION");
      m.calificacionp3=sc.nextDouble();
      System.out.println("SU CALIFICACION ES:"+m.agregar());
      Estudiante e = new Estudiante(nombre,apellido);
      Estudiantes.add(e);
      Materia ma = new Materia(m.nombremateria,m.calificacionp1,m.calificacionp1,m.calificacionp3);
      Materias.add(ma);
     
    }
      catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());  
          
      }}
    public void buscar(){
    for(Estudiante aux:Estudiantes){
        System.out.println("El nombre es:"+aux.getNombre());
        }  
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Como lo has tratado de realizar,agregalo por favor.

Comment: como no entiendo muy bien lo que intenta decir amigo

Comment: te refieres a que adjunte mi codigo bueno esta bien ya lo envio

Answer (score 0):

La intersección de 2 listas se puede hacer asi, dadas dos listas l1 y l2:

```
List<Estudiante> interseccion = l1.stream()
    .filter(l2::contains)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

El único detalle que tienes que agregar a tu clase (porque no la veo) es un metodo equals() que verifique los campos que son necesarios para saber si un registro es el mismo.... *y* un hashcode que también sea significativo.... Eso para complir con el contrato de los collections: https://www.javabrahman.com/corejava/understanding-equals-and-hashcode-contract-when-using-collections-in-java/

En todo caso, serviría sin agregarle nada a la clase si vas averificar las instancias que estén en ambas clases siempre y cuando sean las mismas instancias, no equivalentes (que es lo que los métodos equals y hashcode resuelven para encontrar instancias equivalentes).

Comment: ok gracias si puedes poner un pequeño de como seria esa interseccion no entiendo muy bien esa parte